# Docker Compose can't execute: "Command 'docker-compose' not found"

Tags: server, bash, docker

I have installed the latest Docker Compose as a non-sudo user on Ubuntu Server 20.04 along with docker-rootless daemon in the non-sudo user's directory, using the following:

```
mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins/
curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.2.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
chmod +x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

And verified successful installation with:

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.2.3
```

However, whenever I try to execute `docker-compose up -d` for a `.yml` file that I have created, I get the following output:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list'

Command 'docker-compose' not found, but can be installed with:

snap install docker          # version 20.10.11, or
apt  install docker-compose  # version 1.25.0-1

See 'snap info docker' for additional versions.
```

Docker Compose is not finding the correct `docker.sock` file although my non-root user's `~/.bashrc` file contains:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1007/docker.sock
```

How can I make Docker Compose recognize the correct `docker.sock` file?

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the description of your question. The error you are showing when using `docker-compose` is that the command is not found in your $PATH and not related to the docker.sock issue

Comment: See my answer below - the syntax is wrong. It should be `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose` when using V2.

Comment: @ArturMeinild  you were right on the money... the software package that I installing includes the hyphen in the instructions... thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're making a very basic mistake in your Docker Compose command.

Docker Compose V1 has the command syntax `docker-compose` (`docker-compose` is a separate command).

Docker Compose V2 has the command syntax `docker compose` (`compose` is a subcommand of the `docker` command).

Since you have installed Docker Compose V2 branch, you can't use `docker-compose up -d`, but should instead use the correct V2 syntax:

```
docker compose up -d
```

I would assume that most installation instructions will still use the old syntax `docker-compose` for some time, until V2 has become more mainstream. In the meantime, remember to replace with the new syntax if you're running V2.

If you want to retain compatibility with the old syntax, you could create an alias like this:

```
alias docker-compose='docker compose'
```

This should work for most cases.

As of July 2023, the old Docker Compose V1 syntax is completely deprecated, and only the [V2 syntax is supported](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Comment: There is an error in the documentation. They explain how to install the version two but in the Getting Started section still using docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-4-build-and-run-your-app-with-compose

Comment: Thanks for saving tons of time.