# Why make init did not find docker-compose when setuping docker project?

Tags: docker

I try setup laravel app with docker container on my local kubuntu 22.04 and got error :

```
$ make init
Building containers
docker-compose build --no-cache
make: docker-compose: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:13: build] Error 127
```

I suppose as not long time ago docker-compose has changed it's format I got this error :

```
master@master-at-home:/Project$ sudo apt  install docker-compose
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 59.6.0-1.2) but 59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now in my system I have :

```
master@master-at-home:/Project$ uname -a
Linux master-at-home 6.2.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct  6 10:23:26 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
master@master-at-home:/Project$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
6.2.0-35-generic
x86_64
```

In docker-compose.yml of the project I found :

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

No pointing to real version of docker in this docker-compose file, like I usually have in docker projects

```
version: '3.X'
```

Why I got error with python3-setuptools package and how have I to install docker-compose ?

Would it fix my problem ?

Comment: Try this, and see if it works: [Docker Compose can't execute: "Command 'docker-compose' not found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396689/docker-compose-cant-execute-command-docker-compose-not-found)

Comment: Also, the error about `python3-setuptools` is likely completely unrelated - this should be fixed otherwise (please [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably install `docker-compose-v2` from Universe repos, or `docker-compose-plugin` from the Docker repos (depending on how you installed Docker).

```
sudo apt install docker-compose-v2
```

OR

```
sudo apt install docker-compose-plugin
```

Then, you can make an alias, so that the old `docker-compose` command runs the new command structure (`docker compose`).

```
alias docker-compose='docker compose'
```

Hopefully, this should fix things for you.